# Design-time document for FlowDocument

Tags: wpf, flowdocumentreader

I am trying to set the document of FlowDocumentReader at design-time but cannot figure out how to do it in a pure declarative way. There is no design-time attribute for Document and using DataContext does not work (for obvious reasons I think). What is the best way to this:

- in a declarative way (preferred)
- in a mostly declarative way with some helper code (less preferred)
- using only code (least preferred)

The declarative design-time is important since we are using sketchflow to mockup an application screen where the user can see the (paragraph and character) styles and navigate through the document using these styles.
All suggestions are welcome. 
Thanks, Marc